# How to transfer a row of numbers from MS word to MS excel in columns

Tags: excel, ms-word, transpose

I have 1000 rows of numbers like as in the picture below in MS Word

[Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YADh.png)

How do I get them in excel like in the following picture in excel. Basically, I want to transpose the row into a column. But all those numbers only in one column. So only one column will all the numbers that are in that word file. The order is irrelevant.

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roNvQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

first, your data in word must be on table, if you just create your data in word and column that will be one column if you copy to excel.

second, if you have done with data in table you can copy your data to excel, like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQN0.png)

after that you can use **TRANSPOSE**. 
Block all data than right click choose paste special then **TRANSPOSE**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy & paste the word content to a reasonable text editor (e.g. notepad++).
2. Use the search and replace function to replace whatever is between the numbers (e.g. blanks) with line breaks (\r\n). If everything worked properly, then there is at most 1 number per line.
3. Copy & paste everything from the text editor to Excel.